Loading curl config file through curl API
I'm using libcurl API in a C++11 application. Since curl has several options, I would like the application to be able to load all of the options from a configuration file. I saw that the command-line curl application can do this: https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/configfile.html
However, when looking through the API, and even browsing a bit through the source code, I could not find an easy way of setting all my curl handle's options through a file. Something like:

curl_load_file(CURL * curl, const char* filePath);

or similar. I'm thinking of starting a project of my own that would do this, but it really feels that I am reinventing the wheel.
Is there any easy way of doing this? How?

Is there any easy way of doing this? - No. How? - Look at the curl source files.

libcurl has no API for loading config options from a file. The curl application implements logic to parse a file and make the appropriate API calls. You will have to do the same in your application.

Thanks. It is a bit tricky because the options are all preprocessor symbols defined with #define, so I can't simply use a trivial string comparison to do this. The good thing is I found a way to do this specificaly in my application. The bad part is that it is not generic enough to be a projecct used by other people :(

You would obviously have to parse the file and then compare the values to map them into known API options as needed. For example, when a URL is parsed, pass that string value to curl_easy_setopt(CURLOPT_URL). This can easily be written in a way that other people can use.
